# GPIOZero button not working

Tags: gpio, gpiozero

I've been getting into GPIO recently with the GPIOZero library but when i first tried it today it completely failed. As my first foray into GPIO i set up a circuit to light up an LED with the push of a button, so simple nothing could go wrong, right? I imported the library like so: `from gpiozero import Button, LED` then i set up my components: `led = LED(17)` then the button: `btn = Button(4)` And then this happened:

[image]

I have attempted to re download the library but `sudo apt-get install python3-gpiozero` said that it was the latest version.

This is the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTQx0E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First: what doe this error mean?

Second: How can i fix it?

Comment: It may be a bug.  Try using sudo python to see if you still get the same error message.

Comment: @joan if i run `sudo python3` and then enter in the python commands i get the error but if i save i file with the code it does nothing

Comment: The script works for me (with or without sudo).  I'd guess you have an inconsistent version of the RPi.GPIO module.

Comment: @joan finally got around to experimenting with this some more and it does work with pins 27 and 17 and probably more more but just not with pin number @#%$^&$ 4

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before, when the 1-wire interface has been enabled. If you've enabled 1-wire in Raspberry Pi configuration, you won't be able to use GPIO4 for general use. Try disabling it:

https://github.com/bennuttall/one-wire-temperature-sensor

Comment: Sadly this pi  is no longer in service so I can't test it.